# Does SOAP/JMS should always handle the Fault?

Tags: soap, jms, protocols, standards, fault

Does SOAP/JMS require to handle the Fault message in one-way communication?
In HTTP it's simple, we have HTTP status code with response after sending req.
What about JMS?
I mean let's consider following simplified binding in wsdl:

```
<wsdl:binding>
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/jms"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="ala">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input name="ala"/>
    <wsdl:operation/>
  <soap:binding/>
<wsdl:binding/>
```

In this scenario does SOAP require to wait by the client for the response message with optional Fault (which could always happen)? Or does SOAP Fault is not supported for this scenario/communication protocol and it's in line with the standard?

Answer (score 1):

According to [WS-I 2.0 basic profile](http://ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-2.0-2010-11-09.html#One-Way_Operations) and [WSDL 2.0](https://www.w3.org/2004/07/xml2004-hh/wsdl20-update.html#mep) specifications it is not allowed to define `fault` when there is no `output` in operation definition.

Comment: Thank You Borajs :D